# project a point in 3D on a given plane

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, coordinate-systems

A point in a 3D space is given as $ P(x,y,z) $. I want to find the position of this point projected parallel to the normal on a plane Q defined by $3$ non-collinear points $ Q1(x1,y1,z1), Q2(x2,y2,z2)\; and \;Q3(x3,y3,z3) $.

How to derive this point of projection?

I saw [this entry on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_projection) but I cannot understand it.

I'd prefer an answer that gives the derivation of a $4$-ary transformation function $f$ such that

$ f \; (P, Q1, Q2, Q3) = P' $

where P' is a point in 2D with co-ordinates as $ P'(x',y') $ such that P' is the required projection of P on the plane Q.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $Q_1$, $Q_2$ and $Q_3$ be linearly independent vectors. The formula
$$
n=\frac{(Q_2-Q_1)\times(Q_3-Q_2)}{|(Q_2-Q_1)\times(Q_3-Q_2)|}
$$
defines a unit vector normal to the plane. Let $P$ be a vector, and $\pi(P)$ its normal projection onto the plane. Then,
$$
P-\pi(P)=D\,n
$$
for some $D\in\mathbb{R}$. Keeping in mind that $n$ is orthogonal to the plane, we can write
$$
D=(P-\pi(P))\cdot n=(P-\pi(P))\cdot n+(\pi(P)-Q_1)\cdot n=(P-Q_1)\cdot n
$$
Finally, we have:
$$
\pi(P)=P-\left((P-Q_1)\cdot n\right)n
$$

Answer (score 8):

Alternatively ...

Define $U$, $V$ as in my first answer. Let $N$ be a unit vector normal to the plane, which you can obtain by unitizing the cross product $U \times V$.

Then the projected point $R$ is given by
$$
R = P - \left[(P-Q_1) \cdot N\right]*N
$$

This is essentially the same answer provided by zuggg. I wrote it before seeing his, and decided to keep it since I think it's easier to read. You can decide which one you like better, and how to give credit (if any).

Comment: Can one not accept more than one as answers? Thanks for your explanation.

Comment: You can accept only one answer. But you can upvote several answers, if you want to. And, you can upvote in addition to accepting, if you want to.

Answer (score 3):

Let $U = Q_2 - Q_1$ and $V = Q_3 - Q_1$, and let $R$ be the required projected point. Then, since $R$ lies in the plane of $Q_1$, $Q_2$, $Q_3$, there exist numbers $h$ and $k$ such that 
$$R = Q1 + h*U + k*V$$
The vector $R-P$ is perpendicular to the plane, so $(R-P) \cdot U = 0$ and $(R-P) \cdot V = 0$. Substituting for $R$ gives:
$$
(Q1 + h*U + k*V- P) \cdot U = 0 \\
(Q1 + h*U + k*V- P) \cdot V = 0
$$
which expands to
$$
h*(U \cdot U) + k*(U \cdot V) = (Q1-P) \cdot U  \\
h*(U \cdot V) + k*(V \cdot V) = (Q1-P) \cdot V
$$
Solve these equations for $h$ and $k$ (by Cramer's rule, for example), and then substitute into the first displayed equation above to get $R$.

Comment: How would this be done, for example, if I have the orthogonal vectors for each plane and want to project a point on one plane, down its plane normal to the other, given that the vector space for each plane is similar and each has a selected origin?  I can ask a new question if you think that would be best.

Comment: I think what I actually need is the situation where I know R, but P is unknown, but like I said in the previous comment, I know the orientation of the plane that P is in.